WP Is converting & to &amp; in dynamics URL. How to avoid it?
I need to send a url redirect to a third-party application after a form is submitted with the following structure:
(checkoutlink)?&fn=[field+id="name"]&em=[field+id="email"]&ph=[field+id ="phone"]

And for this, I use the dynamic links of the Elementor form, as it has a custom checkout url field on each product page.
The problem is that WordPress is inserting amp; after &, and this is causing data capture not to work in the third-party application.
How it should work (the URL on dynamic field for redirect after form submission with parameters already filled):
https://payfast.greenn.com.br/73162?&fn=Test+name&em=testemail@test.com&ph=71596845895

What WordPress is doing:
https://payfast.greenn.com.br/73162?&amp;fn=Test+name&amp;em=testemail@test.com&amp;ph=71596845895

You see that in the first link, the fields are being pre-populated. I insert that link on my url field, but then WordPress changes every instance of & with amp;.
How to avoid it?
Plugins I use: Elementor for form, Crocoblock jetengine for url dynamic field.
